# JavaScript continuous EXP and bars reset on level up

Tags: javascript

So, I've made a quick script that works perfectly fine already. However, I'm trying to "translate" it into a progress bar, which is also simple enough, as I've made it for other things already.
HOWEVER, I ran into an issue on the bar resets (which worked). Remember, this is for a very specific thing, so the code might now work properly on other systems and you'd have to change the [data.infos] to test.

```
if (data.infos[3] == 1) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 47 * 100}%">%</div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] == 2) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 95 * 100}%">%</div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  3) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 191 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  4) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 287 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  5) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 479 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  6) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 575 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  7) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 671 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  8) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 767 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  9) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: ${data.infos[6] / 863 * 100}%"></div>`);
    } else if (data.infos[3] ==  10) {
        $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: 100%, color: green"></div>`);
    }
```

This works partially fine. But I think I got the math all wrong and I don't know why I can't figure it out.

HTML line is as follows:

```
<div id="levelBar"></div><br>
```

CSS is also simple and it is as follows:

```
`#levelBar {
    float: left;
    min-height: 10px;
    max-height: 10px;
    min-width: 10vw;
    max-width: 10vw;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #aaaaaa66;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#levelExp {
    float: left;
    min-height: 10px;
    max-height: 10px;
    max-width: 10vw;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #F0CA0E, #CAA700);
    transition: all 0.9s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}`
```

So the progress runs fine for the first level - 0XP to 47XP.
However, when it hits 48XP, it does level up, but it doesn't fully reset the bar to 0%, but rather to 50%~.
Same goes for all other levels.
How can I make it so it fills up at those amounts of XP and max them out at the next one?

```
`Level 1 - (bar at 0)0XP to 47XP(max bar)
Level 2 - (bar at 0)48XP to 95XP(max bar)
Level 3 - (bar at 0)96XP to 191XP(max bar)
```

... And so on.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem explanation

Your problem is simple: There is no way that the bar *can* actually be zero (after it leveled up), because you never reset the total EXP to zero (and you never want to do this anyways).

Consider this:

- On level 2 your total EXP is at least 48. 48 / 95 * 100 = ~50%.
- On level 3 your total EXP is at least 96. 96 / 191 * 100 = ~50%.
- etc.

## Suggested solution:

Change your formula:

- On level 2 your total EXP is at least 48. i.e. (XP - 48) / 95 * 100
- On level 3 your total EXP is at least 96. i.e. (XP - 96) / 191 * 100
- ...

```js
// ...
} else if (data.infos[3] == 2) {
   $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: (${data.infos[6] - 48) / 95 * 100}%">%</div>`);
} else if (data.infos[3] ==  3) {
   $("#levelBar").html(`<div id="levelExp" style="width: (${data.infos[6] - 95) / 191 * 100}%"></div>`);
}
// ...
```

### Parting thought

Consider utilizing centralizing the EXP values, through constants, and instead of writing the HTML per hand having it generated in a loop.